# Silverlight: Tabbing in DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with four rows and a few columns. Only the last column has an item (a button) with `IsTabStop=True`.

If I press tab the button in the first row gets the focus.
If I hit tab a second time the next control outside the grid gets the focus.
If I then hit shift-tab the button in the last row gets the focus.

Is there a way to make the `DataGrid` work like other controls and just tab normally through the four buttons?

Answer (score 1):

For the focus to remain within the `DataGrid`, the current cell needs to be in edit mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838112(v=vs.95).aspx